# Avoid page break between paragraphs with \medskip in between

Tags: page-breaking

Consider this texample

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
Some text

\medskip
\textbf{Mini title}
\medskip

\nopagebreak
Some more text
\end{document}
```

How can I avoid a page break between "Mini title" and "Some more text". I am exploring `\nopagebreak` to this end but to no avail?

Comment: why are you using `\textbf` font change not a propper heading such as `\section*{mini title}` ? latex never allows a page break after section heads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I copied the `\medbreak` command from LaTeX and made a `\mednobreak`. It does a `\nopagebreak` and a `\medskip`. It will attach the first line of the following paragraph to the `\textbf{Mini title}`. Comment the line marked to see the effect.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\mednobreak{\par\ifdim\lastskip<\medskipamount
  \removelastskip\nopagebreak\medskip\fi}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\lipsum[2]

another line % comment to see difference

\medskip
\textbf{Mini title}
\mednobreak
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Avoid using explicit font change commands.

if you use a section heading command the markup is more flexible and LaTeX automatically takes care of not allowing a page break after the heading

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
Some text

\vspace{40\baselineskip}% heading and text stay on this page
%\vspace{41\baselineskip}% heading and text go to next page

Some text

\subsection*{Mini title}

Some more text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you load the `needspace` package and issue the directive

```
\Needspace*{3\baselineskip}
```

immediately before the first `\medskip` directive.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{needspace}
\begin{document}
\dots 

Some text

\Needspace*{3\baselineskip}
\medskip
\textbf{Mini title}
\medskip

Some more text
\end{document}
```